# Bootstrap navbar collapse icon not appearing nor working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement a collapsable navbar on a small project of mine. My problem is when I resize the window, the navbar collapses but the button (even though it's clickable) doesn't appear nor offer me any options.

I don't know if it's a jQuery/JS problem. I'm just a beginner so I just linked some libraries on codepen settings. I took a look at some problems people had concerning this, but none of the solutions helped me.

The codepen link is: https://codepen.io/diegomengue/pen/XgRamN.

Any help on the subject (and also tips of all kind) are appreciated!

Thank you.

HTML:

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-toggleable-sm mx-auto sticky-top'>
  <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed mx-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class='navbar-nav mx-auto'>
     <li class='nav-item'><a href='#sobreMim' class='nav-link'><strong>Diego Mengue</strong></a></li>
     <li class='nav-item'><a href='#portfolio' class='nav-link'>Portfólio</a></li>
     <li class='nav-item'><a href='#contato' class='nav-link'>Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navbar toggler class is expecting navbar-color-scheme type class . Try this pen

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm mx-auto sticky-top'>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed mx-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class='navbar-nav mx-auto'>
      <li class='nav-item'><a href='#sobreMim' class='nav-link'><strong>Diego Mengue</strong></a></li>
      <li class='nav-item'><a href='#portfolio' class='nav-link'>Portfólio</a></li>
      <li class='nav-item'><a href='#contato' class='nav-link'>Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

https://codepen.io/dannybrown/pen/yXXBxK?editors=1100

If you dont want to follow the available color scheme, add styles for navbar-toggler class in your custom styles